# Rails 5 model .update_or_create form Food cant find id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Good Friday

update i am edited sources as you suggest me and include here my routes  but  this happends when i am try to edit action

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"uzivatel", :datum=>nil}, missing required keys: [:datum]
```

and log is

```
Started GET "/uzivatel/2017-07-31/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-31 06:46:45 +0200
Processing by UzivatelController#edit as HTML
```

> Parameters: {"datum"=>"2017-07-31"}
>       User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1],
>   ["LIMIT", 1]]
>       Order Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."datum" = $1 AND "orders"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY
>   "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["datum", "2017-07-31"], ["user_id", 1],
>   ["LIMIT", 1]]
>       (0.6ms)  BEGIN   User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>   [i18n-debug] cs.activerecord.models.order => nil [i18n-debug]
>   cs.activerecord.attributes.order.food => nil [i18n-debug]
>   cs.attributes.food => nil [i18n-debug]
>   cs.activerecord.errors.models.order.attributes.food.required => nil
>   [i18n-debug] cs.activerecord.errors.models.order.required => nil
>   [i18n-debug] cs.activerecord.errors.messages.required => nil
>   [i18n-debug] cs.errors.attributes.food.required => nil [i18n-debug]
>   cs.errors.messages.required => "musí existovat"    (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
>   Rendering uzivatel/edit.html.erb within layouts/application   Rendered
>   uzivatel/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms) Completed
>   500 Internal Server Error in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
>
> [Rollbar] Reporting exception: No route matches {:action=>"update",
>   :controller=>"uzivatel", :datum=>nil}, missing required keys: [:datum]
>   [Rollbar] Scheduling item [Rollbar] Sending item [Rollbar] Success
>   [Rollbar] Details:
>   https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=eab60ff5-b63c-417b-aeb7-55fea4242ed6
>   (only available if report was successful) [Rollbar] Exception uuid
>   saved in env: eab60ff5-b63c-417b-aeb7-55fea4242ed6
>
> ActionView::Template::Error - No route matches {:action=>"update",
>   :controller=>"uzivatel", :datum=>nil}, missing required keys: [:datum]

i am use rails 5 and i dont know why it reports me  cant find food with id
on line,it looklike  it dont loads up food_id from form i am eventually welcome ideas how to rewrite it  in better way.
Anyway thanks for any constructive advices.

```
 @order.update(food_id: Food.find(params[:food_id]))
```

Models:

```
User model has many orders 
Food has many orders
Order belong to user and  Food
```

UzivatelController

```
class UzivatelController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
@date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
@orders = Order.where(:datum => @date.beginning_of_week..@date.end_of_week).where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

 def edit
   @order=Order.where(:datum => params[:datum] ).where(:user_id => current_user.id).first_or_create

  end
  def update
  @order=Order.where(:datum => params[:datum] ).where(:user_id => current_user.id).first_or_create
  params.permit(:food_id)
  if @order.update(food_id: Food.find(params[:food_id]).first)
    redirect_to uzivatel_index_path, notice: 'Objednavka uložena'
  else
   redirect_back(fallback_location: uzivatel_index_path)
  end
end


def delete
end
private
def order_params
  params.permit(:food_id)
end
```

end

index.html.erb

```
<div >
<h2 >
<%= link_to "<", date: @date.prev_week %>
<%=l(@date, :format => :monthyear) %>
<%= link_to ">", date: @date.next_week %>
</h2>
<%= calendar @date do |date| %>
 #calendar is helper  to render week calendar 
<% if can_change?(date)%>

<%=link_to l( date),controller: "uzivatel", action: "edit", datum: @date%>
<%else%>
  Nelze vybrat
<%end%>
<%if @orders.ke_dni(date).any?%>
<div class="user_orders_choice">
<%= @orders.ke_dni(date).first.food.name%>
</div>
<%else%>
<div class="user_orders_no_choice">nic</div>
<%end%>
<% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_with url: uzivatel_update_path,method: :put, local: true do |form| %>
<%= form.collection_select(@food_id, Food.all, :id, :name)%>
<%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get '/uzivatel/index', as: 'uzivatel_index'
get '/uzivatel/:datum/edit(.:format)', to: 'uzivatel#edit', as: 'uzivatel_edit'
put '/uzivatel/:datum(.:format)', to: 'uzivatel#update', as: 'uzivatel_update'
delete 'uzivatel/:datum(.:format)',to: 'uzivatel#delete', as: 'uzivatel_destroy'
get 'admin/index'
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'my'
resources :users , path: 'admin/uzivatele'
resources :suppliers , path: 'admin/dodavatele'
resources :departments , path: 'admin/oddeleni'
resources :svatkies , path: 'admin/svatky'
resources :foods , path: 'admin/nabidky'


 # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some issues. Please try to fix them and re-run your code.

In `update` action in `UzivatelController`

Use

`@order.update(food_id: Food.find(params[:food_id]))`

Instead of

`@order.update(food_id: Food.find(params[:food_id]).first)`

In `edit.html.erb`

Pass object in url_helper

```
<%= form_with url: uzivatel_update_path(datum: `your dataum value`, food_id: `your food id`), method: :put, local: true do |form| %>
<%= form.collection_select(@food_id, Food.all, :id, :name)%>
<%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If you still face any error share the error trace so that we can debug it easily

Comment: @TomasKrmela I updated my answer. Please have a look at it
I made changes is `edit.html.erb`

`form_with url: uzivatel_update_path(datum: 'your dataum value', food_id: 'your food id'), method: :put, local: true do |form|`